# Convert Xcode FAT static library to regular static library?

Tags: ios, xcode, spidermonkey

`Gameclosure` distrubutes precompiled `SpiderMonkey` for `iOS`. But the problem is that they use `FAT static library`. And the tools I am using on the JB iphone cannot recognize such a library.

FAT library basically has two libraries inside, one for simulator (`i386`) and one for iPhone (`arm`). So is there a way to extract only arm version and save as regular `static library`?

*PS. I am really used to compile on iPhone, I do not want to go back to Xcode.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "lipo" tool to extract one architecture, e.g.

```
lipo -thin armv7 -output SpiderMonkey-armv7.a SpiderMonkey.a
```